How to package software with parallel imports?
How can I package the following minimal example in such a way that bar.py is still able to import foo.py. Preferably, without needing to change the python code, but by passing something like -m trend.bar into pyinstaller.
Minimal Example
Given the structure:
.
├── toast
│   └── foo.py # VARIABLE = 42
└── trend
    └── bar.py 

Where bar.py contains
from toast import foo

print(foo.VARIABLE)

I would execute this like python3 -m trend.bar without issues.
What I have tried

I tried installing without giving any additional information regarding the structure. Import didn't work.
I tried pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. trend/bar.py. Import didn't work.


Could you clarify you mean by packaging? Are you asking specifically about using pyinstaller, or about packaging the project in general (i.e. into distribution package)?

Sorry for being unclear. Both is relevant for me.
